# How to change address type while composing e-mail in Thunderbird using only the keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird for my e-mails, but I can't seem to find a way to do this **with my keyboard only**:

1. I press <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> to compose a new e-mail message
2. I type in my first recipient's e-mail address, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Now the cursor is on the second line, for the second recipient - but I'd like to make this a `Cc:` (not a `To:`) recipient.....

How do I do that, with my keyboard? I'd prefer not to use the mouse at this point.  Is there a shortcut for this? Can't seem to find any reference on how to do this.

Comment: In a recent new build, the shift-tab functionality no longer works. I do this keyboard sequence frequently and for some reason it no longer is supported. This is a disappointing accessibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After step 2 (after hitting Enter), Shift-Tab will highlight the "To" button. Press down arrow to change it to CC and Tab again to move to provide the CC address.

Answer (score 2):

This calls for the very nice "Nostalgy" Add-on, available through the normal Add-ons manager in Thunderbird.  With it, at the beginning of the addressee field, you can just type "CC[space]".  This will change the address type, and clear the "CC " that you just typed, leaving you in a position to start entering the email address.
(Nostalgy also has other functionality to enable keyboard operation.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you expand your answer a little?  What is that extension and where can people find it?  Your instructions to type CC[space]: that is just done as part of entering the recipient's name and the extension interprets that and changes the setting?

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @James6M recommended it, I tried the [Nostalgy Add-on for Thunderbird](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/nostalgy/).

Typing `cc[space]` in a recipients field changes its type to "Cc:"

[image: Address entry example with Nostalgy Addon]

Comment: Welcome back to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center. Don't copy from already given answer.